# Настройка navbar'a

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Помогите пожалуйста настроить navbar.
Нужно, чтобы, как он вначале начинается, так и заканчивался, без следующего продолжения, которое начинается само...
 У меня ровно 3 категории. Нужно, чтобы меню закончилось после третей категории, и дальше уже | не шло...
Как можно сделать так?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.navbar-2 .navbar-collapse  {
 background: radial-gradient(#265a88 , #337ab7);
}
.navbar-2 {
  
  
  width: 939px;

  
}

.navbar-2.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-2.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color: #6699FF;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #4c4e5a 0%, #2c2d33 100%);
}

.navbar-2 .navbar-nav > li > a {
 color: #FFF;
 font-size: 13px;

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
      <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-2">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse2">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse2">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>
          <a href="catalog.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></span> Все товары</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="signalizaciya.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera"></span> Сигнализация</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="termostat.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire"></span> Управление комфортом</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Не совсем понятно, что Вы хотите, но предположу:

[ПРИМЕР на JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/xuhuqa/edit?css,output)

```css
.navbar-2 .navbar-collapse  {
 background: radial-gradient(#265a88 , #337ab7);
}


.navbar-2.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-2.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color: #6699FF;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #4c4e5a 0%, #2c2d33 100%);
}

.navbar-2 .navbar-nav > li > a {
 color: #FFF;
 font-size: 13px;
}

.navbar-2 .navbar-nav > li > a {
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
}

.navbar-2 .navbar-nav > li:last-of-type > a {
  border-right: none;
}

@media (min-width: 768px){
  
  .navbar-nav {
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .navbar-nav > li {
      float: left;
      width: 30%;
  }
  
  .navbar-2 { 
     width: 939px;  
   }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
      <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-2">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse2">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse2">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>
          <a href="catalog.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></span> Все товары</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="signalizaciya.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera"></span> Сигнализация</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="termostat.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire"></span> Управление комфортом</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Если нужно, чтобы меню не на всю ширину растягивалось, тогда просто

```
.navbar-2 .navbar-nav > li:last-of-type > a {
  border-right: none;
}
```

или

```
.navbar-2 .navbar-nav > li:last-of-type  {
  border-right: none;
}
```

Comment: Ему нужно было убрать вертикальную черту после последнего пункта меню. :))

Comment: Я добавила на этот случай ответ)  `border-right: none;`

Comment: @ElenaSemenchenko Спасибо вам большое, вы как обычно выручили!